# Is there a way to catch a JavaScript exception in Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop

I have a `<core-icon>` element like

```dart
<polymer-element name="app-element">
  <template>
    <core-icon icon="{{icon}}"></core-icon>
  </template>
  <script ...>
</polymer-element>
```

```dart
@CustomTag('app-element')
class AppElement extends PolymerElement {
  AppElement.created() : super.created();

  @observable
  String icon = 'menu';

  clickHandler(e) {
    icon = null;
  }
}
```

This leads to this exception

```dart
Exception caught during observer callback: TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null
    at core-icon.Polymer.updateAlt (http://localhost:63342/core-elements/packages/core_elements/src/core-icon/core-icon.html:188:50)
    at core-icon.Polymer.updateIcon (http://localhost:63342/core-elements/packages/core_elements/src/core-icon/core-icon.html:147:14)
    at core-icon.g.invokeMethod (http://localhost:63342/core-elements/packages/polymer/src/js/polymer/polymer.js:13:25932)
    at core-icon.g.notifyPropertyChanges (http://localhost:63342/core-elements/packages/polymer/src/js/polymer/polymer.js:13:24037)
    at Object.x.report_ (http://localhost:63342/core-elements/packages/polymer/src/js/polymer/polymer.js:12:18274)
    at Object.S.check_ (http://localhost:63342/core-elements/packages/polymer/src/js/polymer/polymer.js:12:22612)
    at c (http://localhost:63342/core-elements/packages/polymer/src/js/polymer/polymer.js:12:12181) polymer.concat.js:4861x.report_ polymer.concat.js:4861S.check_ polymer.concat.js:5264c
```

In my opinion this is a but in `<core-icon>` and I'm going to create an issue but my question is anyway:

Is there a way to catch such a JavaScript exception in Dart?

I of course tried to wrap the line `icon = null;` with a `try/catch` or `window.onError.listen((e)...);` without success though.

Comment: You have to try/catch from the beginning of the call. That's why try/catch surrounding `icon = null` does not help.

Why don't you use: `<template if="{{icon!=null}}"><core-icon icon="{{icon}}"></core-icon></template>`. I don't think this is a bug, why do you want the icon to be null?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by `the beginning of the call`. I can check against `null` in binding or in my code but I still think the `core-icon` should not throw when `icon` becomes `null`. I do/did not set it to `null` intentionally but I stumbled upon this because in some situations the model or the field in of the model `icon` is bound to became `null`. The above code is simplified to make a small example that allows to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Maybe there is a way to register a global error handler that allows to handle such exceptions?

Comment: Even zones don't catch errors. I tried `runZoned(() { icon = null; }, onError: (e) { print('onError'); });` without success.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it!

Comment: The variable becomes `null` at some point and then at some other point a script or change listener or anything else will check values and propagate null to core-icon. That's what I meant by "beginning of the call". You are not responsible for the propagation of the new value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't actually tried it but I guess it is the solution:

Source: https://github.com/dart-lang/core-elements/issues/148#issuecomment-62574668

It looks like the actual issue is the exception is being caught on the js side and then just printed to the console, so that is why we can't get access to it. They do set Observer._errorThrownDuringCallback to true though, so you can add the following in your test and it will fail appropriately:

```dart
expect(context['Observer']['_errorThrownDuringCallback'], false,
    reason: 'Setting icon to null shouldn\'t throw an error.');
```